# YAML inventory parsing error

Tags: python, ansible, python-3.6, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

`hosts.ini`

```
[local]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

`hosts.yaml`

```
local:
  hosts:
    127.0.0.1:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
```

then I run `ansible local -m ping -i hosts.ini` I got expected ouput, then I run `ansible local -m ping -i hosts.yaml` I got:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/elruso/projects/ansible/hosts.yaml with ini plugin: /home/elruso/projects/ansible/hosts.yaml:5: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: local
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/elruso/projects/ansible/hosts.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: local
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

According to [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) I can use yaml files as inventory without problems. How can I specify to use the yml plugin?

```
$ansible --version
ansible 2.4.0.0
config file = /home/elruso/projects/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/home/elruso/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /home/elruso/.virtualenvs/ansible/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /home/elruso/.virtualenvs/ansible/bin/ansible
python version = 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 08:43:29) [GCC 5.4.1 20170519]
```

**Update**: [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30977) opened

Comment: Should `127.0.0.1:` have the `:` at the end?

Comment: @JimWright yes http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is reproducible in Python 3 and looks like a bug.

Use Python 2 instead of Python 3, as the latter is [not officially supported yet](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/python_3_support.html).

Comment: Looks like sad true, but I see "Ansible supports Python version 3.5 and above only." following your link and I have Python 3.6.2

Comment: But it's not like you can take any string out of context and claim it's true. The article starts clearly with a statement "tech preview of Python 3 support*. Within the preview only >3.5 is included.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in ansible 2.4.0 on python 3 (trying to find the `.yml` bytes in a list of strings).

This bug has been fixed in this commit https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/72bdf7aa7e1b867380201092dff65338d59cd8fa, it may be released as 2.4.1.

Comment: But you are aware that you are replying to the same person who submitted the issue on GitHub?

Comment: Yes, but don't worry I also documented it on the issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30977#issuecomment-333460412 so anyone landing here or on github can understand what is happening and when it's expected to be released.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the inventory file and recreating it on the ansible controller fixed it for me.